# Positioning links in CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, hyperlink

Edit: here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hSny/

I'm trying to position links with an image behind it in CSS. This is a preview of how I like to have it:

[preview http://piclair.com/data/odjkf.jpg](http://piclair.com/data/odjkf.jpg)

The Words Home, Campagne, etc need to be centered in the menu bar. The HTML may be ugly now, I have tried nummerous things but I can't get it positioned properly.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="nav">
<li><div id="current_page"><p class="navlink"><a href="home.html"><img src="img/Menu_Home_Selected.png"></a></p></div></li>
</ul>

<!-- end of navigation -->
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#navigation{
background-image: url(img/Navbar.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:955px;
color: #FFF;
float: left;
border:1px solid blue;
}

#current_page {
margin: -22 0 0 0px; 
width:164px;
min-height: 124px;
background-image: url(img/Selected.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nav {
min-height: 28px;
margin: 5 0 0 -14px;
}

#nav ul, li {
list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
width:164px;
}

.navlink p (
display: block;
margin: 35 35 35 35px;
}
```

Right now it looks like this: 
[preview http://piclair.com/data/mdc5z.jpg](http://piclair.com/data/mdc5z.jpg)

Comment: What does it look like right now? :-)

Comment: you might need display: block and text-align: center; on #nav li. and then you'll need to float the li items, vertical align them in the middle etc

Comment: @ninetwozero I have added how it looks right now ;)
kalpaitch: thx, I will try that right now

Comment: A very basic thing which I don't see anywhere is width to the <a> tag or <p> tag. Without assigning widths (corresponding to those your image), it'll be difficult to position. I'd recommend creating a sample somewhere so that one of us could help you out.

I see that you've added how this looks like right now. Looks like there might be some problem with the z-index as well. But unless you give a sample,I can't really say what the problem is.

Comment: @kalpaitch; I can't vertical align the li items, or put a margin on them because the li items contain the yellow background image. If I change something to those li items then the background image will move with it

Comment: @Forza In your css, I don't see the li items having a background. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Aditya Saxena Ah I'm sorry, there's a div (current_page) inside the li items containing the link. That div has the background. I have created a jsFiddle so you can try something: http://jsfiddle.net/7hSny/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things about your markup that could be optimized (as you mentioned, "ugly").  Don't use images where you can use web colors.  For image text, put the actual text that the image represents into the html and use `background-image` for the actual jpg in the css.  Vertically centering is not as easy as it should be (unless you're using table cells), but you can use top/bottom padding or line-height in a lot of cases.

[Here's a fiddle with a few things updated](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/kNd4V/1/). Hope this helps.

Also, check out this [blog post](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) with various vertical alignment methods.  One of these should work for you if mine does not.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish :) Thank you very much Scrimothy! It works perfect. Also thx for the blogpost, that will be really useful in future cases :). I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: forgive me for asking again, but if I use this technique outside block elements it does not work. How can I ident text for normal links with an image behind it? The links are not within <li> tags this time. A solution I come across many times is to use H1 tags, but that does not work as I don't want each H1 tag to be on a new line

Comment: Hmm but the cursor changes in a pointer whenever you hover over the invisbile text. Still not ideal... got any ideas?

Comment: you could set `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` on your image link.  This will allow `text-indent` to be used.  Note: inline-block does not work in old ie versions, so google "ie inline-block" for solutions.  Also, you should never have more than one `h1` tag on a page (or in html5, more than one `h1` per page section).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves it..I'll update with rest of the details once I know if this is what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hSny/7/

I corrected the html though.

```
    <div id="navigation">
<ul id="nav">
<li><div id="current_page"><p class="navlink"><a href="home.html"><img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/30ihnkk.png"></a></p></div></li>
</ul>

<!-- end of navigation -->
</div>
```

Comment: Ehm it's not exactly solving the problem. It's not centered yet and the yellow background needs to merge in the yellow area above and beneath it like I had before. See the first image in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the same technique as [gettyimages](http://www.gettyimages.com/) ([and their css spritesheet](http://www.gettyimages.com/images/globalnav/sp-gnav_fr-06.png)) and run for a simple css spritesheet. That way, you will make better use of semantic and styling.

Consider a navigation with a list :

```
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='home'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li class='campagne'><a href='#'>Campagne</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Then, you stylize it with a simple CSS :

```
ul.nav
{
   display: block;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

ul.nav li
{
   float:left;
   display: block;
}

ul.nav li a
{
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   background: url(img/nav.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

And then use a simple spritesheet to "paint" your buttons ([tutorial for spritesheets](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)) :

```
ul.nav li.home a
{
   width: 50px;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
}

ul.nav li.home a:hover { background-position: 0px -50px; }

ul.nav li.campagne a
{
   width: 80px;
   background-position: 50px 0px;
}

ul.nav li.campagne a:hover { background-position: 50px -50px; }
```